# Python automatically converts the numerator and denominator of some fractions into big numbers. Why?

Tags: python, fractions, python-fractions

Here is an example:

```
x = frac(1,3)
x
Out[138]: Fraction(1, 3)
y = frac(5/39)
y
Out[140]: Fraction(288692283805801, 2251799813685248)
print(x+y)
3117876665102651/6755399441055744
x+y
Out[142]: Fraction(3117876665102651, 6755399441055744)
```

Why is 5/39 automatically converted to 288692283805801/2251799813685248?
Using Python 3.7.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5/39 is a floating point number, that's not representable as 5/39 exactly. The fraction with large numerator and denominator is the rational that exactly represents the floating point number that approximates 5/39.

Try `fractions.Fraction(5, 39)` instead.

A similar example is given in the docs for the fractions module, with `Fraction(1.1)` not returning `Fraction(11, 10)` as one might naively expect. https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Comment: Rookie mistake, thanks for the help.

Comment: Your first sentence is unclear. I can't even tell whether with 5/9 you're talking math or `float` (the style suggests the former, for the latter I'd expect `5/9`).

Comment: And "representable as 5/39" doesn't make sense to me in either interpretation :-)